# Duvida Limpeza Arquivo CSV com PYthon

Tags: python, csv

Tenho um Relatório em CSV com os dados no modelo abaixo(coloquei 1 registro para não poluir):

```
session_id,session_date,client_user_id,professional_user_id,contact_reasons
60e7a5939beb2200116859cc,2021-07-09T23:00:00Z,5f4bfbb5d7e0014e10e9653b,5e1d48550c3e7c3b9989df01,"[""reason:self-knowledge"",""reason:borderline"",""reason:love-relationship""]"
```

Usei esse codigo para limpar e oganizar os dados com python e biblioteca CSV:

```
import csv
with open("arquivos/events_edit.csv",'r') as relatorio:
    data = relatorio.read()
    data = data.replace('"','')
    data = data.replace('reason:','')
    linhas = data.split('\n')
    dados = csv.DictReader(linhas)
    for dado in dados:
        print(dado)
```

Colocando em dicionário a ideia é poder chamar pela key e "quebrar" o arquivo em 2 relatórios diferentes:

1. Contendo as colunas `session_id`, `session_date`, `client_user_id` e `professional_user_id`
2. Contendo as colunas `session_id` e todo o conteudo de `contact_reasons`

Porem a impressão do objeto dado sai de um modo que não consigo jogar pra nenhum lugar (quebrou o conteudo de `contat_reasons` em 2 colunas e uma recebeu nome de `None`) :

```
{
  'session_id': '60e7a5939beb2200116859cc',
  'session_date': '2021-07-09T23:00:00Z',
  'client_user_id': '5f4bfbb5d7e0014e10e9653b',
  'professional_user_id': '5e1d48550c3e7c3b9989df01',
  'contact_reasons': '[self-knowledge',
  None: ['borderline', 'love-relationship]']
}
```

Ele criou esse campo de nome `None`, que não consigo puxar para nenhum lugar.

Alguem ve solução?

Answer (score -1):

Como a linha tem mais vírgulas do que o cabeçalho ele criou uma nova coluna chamada None.

Podemos usar regex para substituir as vírgulas que estão entre parênteses por outro caractér.

```
import csv
import re
with open("file.csv",'r') as relatorio:
    data = relatorio.read()
    data = data.replace('"','')
    data = data.replace('reason:','')
    data = re.sub(',(?=((?!\[).)*?\])', '|', data)
    data = data.replace('[','')
    data = data.replace(']','')
    linhas = data.split('\n')
    dados = csv.DictReader(linhas)
    for dado in dados:
        print(dado)
```